# typedef, arrays and pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, casting, typedef, c-preprocessor

I am studying a code written in C language.

The following part isn't clear for me:

```
typedef uint8_t data_t[4][4];

typedef struct {
   data_t *data;
   ...
} my_struct;
```

The thing that I don't understand is, what is the type of `data`?

Plus, I want to assign values to this variable.
For example, in the code there is:

```
my_struct st;
st.data = (int8_t *)array
```

where array is defined as `int8_t *array`.

I don't understand how this assignation works, could someone explain it clearly?

To finish, is it possible to assign values to my `data_t` variable without declaring it as a pointer in my structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The thing that I don't understand is, what is the type of data?

The type of `data` is a pointer to a two-dimensional array. That is `uint8_t(*data)[4][4]`.

See [C right-left rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) for deciphering C declarations.

> Plus, I want to assign values to this variable `st.data = (int8_t *)array`.

In this case `array` must have the same layout as `uint8_t[4][4]` array. Since arrays are contiguous in `C`, that `array` must have at least 4 * 4 elements of type `int8_t`.

The fact that you have to cast the `array` with `(uint8_t*)` first implies that `array` has a different type and that may cause trouble.

Note that this is a pointer assignment only, not an element-wise copy of `array`.

> is it possible to assign values to my data_t variable without declaring it as a pointer in my structure?

It is possible if `data` is not a pointer, i.e. declare it as `data_t data;`. And then copy into it using `memcpy`.

Answer (score 2):

This declaration

```
typedef uint8_t data_t[4][4];
```

declares name `data_t` as an alias for type `uint8_t [4][4]`.

Thus in the structure definition

```
typedef struct {
   data_t *data;
   ...
} my_struct;
```

member data is a pointer of type `data_t *` that is the same as `uint8_t ( * )[4][4]`.

So it is a pointer to a two-dimensional array of pointers to objects of type `uint8_t

Arrays do not have the assignment operator. You have to copy elements of one array into another.

If for example you have another one-dimensional array of pointers like

```
uint8_t *array[4];
```

you could write

```
my_struct st;
st.data = malloc( sizeof( data_t ) );
memcpy( st.( *data )[0], array, 4 * sizeof( uint8_t * ) );
```

Take into account that as the `data` is a pointer you have at first to allocate memory where you are going to copy objects of type `uint8_t *`.